# How to activate a specific Terminator profile from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, terminal, gnome-terminator

I have saved a few Terminator profiles with different colors etc.
How is it possible to activate a specific profile from the command line, or initially run terminator with a specific profile?

The main goal is to be able to activate profile "Prod" when we ssh to production, and "Stage" when we ssh to the staging-environment. So if there is such a terminator option then an alias can run the ssh command and then change the profile adequately.

Comment: A partial answer can be found here: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/857348/activate-a-specific-terminator-profile-from-the-command-line/857393#857393)

Comment: Cross-posted as per the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857348/activate-a-specific-terminator-profile-from-the-command-line/857393#857393) in the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use the command

```
terminator -p <profile_name> &
```

to start Terminator with the desired profile.

(The `&` is to run Terminator in the background so it doesn't block the shell.)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to open a new tab with a different profile:

```
terminator --new-tab -p profile_name
```

I think there is no way to change the profile of the currently active window or tab.

Comment: It also changes the default profile to be the `profile_name`, so every new tab will be executed under the `profile_name` profile until Terminator is closed. Frankly, I don't understand the logic behind Terminator's profile handling. To me, it's a weird and unintuitive UX. And, according to other questions, I'm not alone.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [this](https://github.com/GratefulTony/TerminatorHostWatch)  Terminator plugin that watches for the hostname and applies profiles accordingly. It hasn't been touched for a while, so I can't say whether it works or not.